# Python - Download EXE File Using Requests, Directly to Memory

Tags: python

I need to download **EXE** through *requests* and put in `pefile.PE`.

I've tried:

```
responseEXE = requests.get('PATH_TO_EXE');
pe_payload = pefile.PE(io.BytesIO(responseEXE.content))
with open(io.BytesIO(responseEXE.content)) as h_payload:
    payload_data = h_payload.read()
```

But I'm getting error:

```
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not _io.BytesIO
```

I also tried `bytes()` but still didn't work.

Comment: Try `pe_payload = pefile.PE(data=responseEXE.content)`

Answer (score 0):

Since your question doesn't say at what step you get this error, I'll assume that it's in the `with open()` section.

Indeed, `open()` doesn't accept an IO object, but a string (or b-string, or pathilb.Path...)corresponding to the **path** of the file you want to open.

But in fact you already have the content you want, as BytesIO! This content is in your `response` object, through the attribute `content`.

So it should work with the following code (I also add comments on code formatting):

```
response_exe = requests.get('PATH_TO_EXE') # variable should be named in snake case, and no need for semicolon at the end of the line

data = response_exe.content
```

What confuses you is that `requests` returns you a content (a big byte string, say) in your memory, not a file on your computer. It saves nothing on your computer.